# TestNG Test getting failed when two test cases are being executed using Selenide. I am new to selenide

Tags: java, testng, selenide

Can somebody help me, please? I'm working with Selenide framework using TestNG and Java.My test are getting failed while running multiple @Test annotations for single @Test it is working[Console error eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRep8.png)

```
public class LoginTest {

    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest() {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ".//src//test//resources//Drivers//chromedriver.exe");
        Configuration.browser = "chrome";
        Configuration.timeout = 5000;
        open("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/");

    }

    @Test
    public void Test1() {

        $(By.id("txtUsername")).setValue("Admin");
        $(By.id("txtPassword")).setValue("admin123");
        $(By.id("btnLogin")).click();
        $(By.id("welcome")).shouldHave(text("Welcome Admin"));

    }

    @Test
    public void Test2() {

        $(By.id("txtUsername")).setValue("Admin");
        $(By.id("txtPassword")).setValue("admin123");
        $(By.id("btnLogin")).click();
        $(By.id("welcome")).shouldHave(text("Welcome Admin"));
        $(By.id("welcome")).click();
        $(By.xpath("//a[@href='/index.php/auth/logout']")).click();

    }

}
```

Comment: Well, the screenshot of console error clearly says that when the 2nd test starts, it tries to locate the `txtUsername` element and it can't. It probably does that because you are already logged in. Try adding an @AfterTest function which clicks on 'Sign out'/'Log out'.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages, along with "[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812)". Please remove the image, and copy the _text_ of the error message into your question, formatting it appropriately for readability.

Answer (score 2):

from your console error you can see that `Element not found`

```
Element not found {By.id: txtUsername}
```

please check if the element -> exist of visible

Answer (score 2):

First, you don't need

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ".//src//test//resources//Drivers//chromedriver.exe");
```

Since Selenide 4.7 contains WebDriverManager - a library that can automatically download latest webdriver binary file. You don't need to care about downloading geckodriver.exe or chromedriver.exe and adding it to PATH. So you can just remove this line.
Also, you may add    `Configuration.startMaximized = true;`

For the parallel execution, I would suggest you create a new class for example
TestNGBase with the tag `@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)` and put there the action before each test. Also, each test inherits from this class

```
public class LoginTest extends TestNGBase
```

So, Test1() and Test2() should be in diff classes
If you want to have more than one test steps you can, but in the class as testStep1() , testStep2() for example.

if you want to keep this set up you already have you may use

```
@BeforeMethod instead of @BeforeTest
```